# Customize the iPhone Callkit calling screen for VOIP apps

Tags: ios, iphone, voip, callkit

I'm using the new CallKit framework to receive incoming VOIP calls using the system UI.

Is it possible to add custom information to the system calling screen - for example a photo or extra text / a new UIView?

Or is it possible to build your own calling screen and have that display in the same way?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to customize the incoming caller's name which is shown in CallKit's native incoming call UI by setting the `localizedCallerName` property of the [CXCallUpdate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit/cxcallupdate) class. And if the user has an entry in their Contacts app relating to the handle specified in the CXCallUpdate's `remoteHandle` property, then that Contact's photo will be shown if there is one.

If you are interested in additional ways to customize the native CallKit UI I recommend filing an enhancement request using Apple's [Bug Reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com) system.

Comment: Apart from the contacts route, there's still (as of iOS 14) no way to customize the Voip call screen with an image?

Comment: Will it be possible to increase font size of the CallKit's UI?